# OSGi Compendium (R6) Annotations + Felix SCR 2.0.0 + Karaf 3.0.6

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, apache-felix

I'm changing my code from Felix SCR annotations to OSGi Compendium R6.

When I want to start my Karaf container, my bundle needs the capability osgi.extender to start correctly.
I could see this is provided by org.apache.felix.scr >= 2.0.0 (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.scr)

Now the problem:
I have the version 1.8.4 of org.apache.felix.scr in my Karaf container (this is a MUST as some bundle has a filter to this version), when I try to put the two versions, my container NEVER CAME UP.

How can I debug this kind of behaviour ? can I get the osgi.extender capability from another place ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a suggestion: It is know that Pax Runner doesn't work well with Felix.scr >= 2.0.0 and Karaf.

You should test updating your pax version to 4.11.0

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried updating your Karaf to version 4.1.x ?

[Here](https://github.com/apache/karaf/blob/master/RELEASE-NOTES), you can see that this version of Karaf already provides support to Felix SCR 2.0.6.

Answer (score 0):

If you are encountering the issue due to multiple bundles you can consider blacklisting of unwanted bundle .

For application specific bundle we can change the import range say [1.8.5,2) or something but for system level bundles its hard to configure